# NRefactory - missing file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net, nrefactory

I am still getting System.IO.FileNotFound Exception when I even try to use NRefactory.
I tried many ways to get it working:
- Used NuGet package, which istalled Mono.Cecil automatically
- downloaded NRefactory and Mono.Cecil, and compiled all DLL's from VS2010.

What am I doing wrong?
Here is error dump:

```
    [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]   
    {"Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.NRefactory, Version=4.2.0.8783,
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=efe927acf176eea2' or one of its dependencies. 
    The system cannot find the file specified.":"ICSharpCode.NRefactory, 
    Version=4.2.0.8783, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=efe927acf176eea2"}  
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

EDIT:
This is code which causes problems:

```
    List<CodeElement> methodsInvokedByGivenMethod = GetInvokedMethods(methodName, fileName);
```

And this is a body of method:

```
    private List<CodeElement> GetInvokedMethods(string methodName, string itemWhereMethodIs)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am here");
        try
        {
            using (var fs = File.OpenRead(itemWhereMethodIs))
            {
                using (var parser = ParserFactory.CreateParser(SupportedLanguage.CSharp, new StreamReader(fs)))
                {
                    parser.Parse();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException fnf)
        {
            // This exception arises in Nrefactory...WTF? 0_0
            SetToolStripText("There is exception :(");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

What is more important, Exception is not being catched by try-catch block within this method, but occurs outside this method -> when it is called, but before any line of code within it.

Comment: In what line of code you get this error?

Comment: Where did you download NRefactory from? The NuGet package is version 5.0, but the exception message mentions 4.2.

Comment: The answer is pretty easy and actually shows my stupidity: Always make dlls auto-added to your assemblies!

Comment: Could you please add an answer (answer your own question) and not put the answer in the comments. And tell us how you "made dlls auto added"